# Delay item hover by 1 second using webkit-animation CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, webkit

I have tried multiple ways to delay the hover of a dropdown menu item by 1 second.

`transition-delay:1s;` does not work. I was advised to do this through a webkit-animation with a 1s.

Here is my CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .bss-megamenu-fw .dropdown-menu {
        -webkit-animation: 0.1s linear 1s normal forwards 1 fadein;
    }
}

@keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    83% { opacity:1; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    83% { opacity:1; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

I am at a loss because this doesn't work. How can I get my delay?

Comment: are you aware that you need to keep the mouse at least one second on the element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following to the `.bss-megamenu-fw .dropdown-menu` class:

`animation: 0.1s linear 0.5s normal forwards 1 fadein;`